# Python PIL crop doesn't crop image

Tags: python, django, image, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

I have the following function to crop an image:

```
def crop(original_image):


    original_image = Image.open(original_image)
    original_image.crop((25, 25, 50, 50))
    #original_image.load()

    thumb_io = StringIO.StringIO()
    original_image.save(thumb_io, format='JPEG')

    thumb_file = InMemoryUploadedFile(thumb_io, None, 'foo2.jpg', 'image/jpeg',
                                  thumb_io.len, None)


    return thumb_file
```

The image saved is just the original image without any size edits.  I tried with both the load and not the load, but that didn't make a difference.

The original image is 300 x 450.

What am I doing wrong that the image isn't saving with any of the cropping edits?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change this line:

```
   original_image =  original_image.crop((25, 25, 50, 50))
```

because the return value of crop function is a rect area but you don't save it!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I needed to extract the crop return value out to a variable:

```
img_io = StringIO.StringIO()
    original_image = Image.open(original_image)
    new_image = original_image.crop((20, 20, 125, 125))
    new_image.save(img_io, format='JPEG', quality=100)
    img_content = ContentFile(img_io.getvalue(), 'foo6.jpg')

    return img_content
```

Comment: Indeed, the crop function returns a new image object. The original image is untoched. Don't forget to mark the answer that lead you to this as the 'accepted answer' ;-)

Answer (score -1):

you might need to change the line

```
thumb_file = InMemoryUploadedFile(thumb_io, None, 'foo2.jpg', 'image/jpeg',
                              thumb_io.len, None)
```

**to**

```
thumb_file = ContentFile(thumb_io.getvalue(), 'foo2.jpg')
```

i guess you planned to save the image file into your db